# How to use nodemon in a Docker node project?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I'm creating a docker node application with a postgres DB. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use an official node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:10

# Set the working directory to /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app/

# Copy package.json to /home/app
COPY package.json .

# Bundle app source to /home/app
COPY . .

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production
RUN npm install

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

CMD npm run dev
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  brewmaster: 
    build: .
    image: myUser/brew_backend:latest
    ports: 
      - 7000:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/brewmaster
      - PORT=3000
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=brewmaster
```

So I have sync my volumes so when I do a local change and I save, I'm able to see the change in my container. However, when I refresh my web page, I don't see the change.

In my package.json file, I have this line to run nodemon:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  }
```

How can I see my changes in my navigator when I save changes in my code? Do I use nodemon correctly? (I run `npm run dev` in my Dockerfile)

I'm using docker on Windows with hyper-V.

EDIT

I found the solution by putting this in my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:7000 server.js"
  }
```

So nodemon listening to host port 7000 and detect file changes.